# fetch data grouped by month using mysql interval

Tags: mysql

I want records from last 1 year from my purchase table grouped by month. its important to mention there is no purchase in last two month including current. mysql query is like following

```
SELECT Year(purchasedate) as y ,Month(purchasedate) as m, Count(*) FROM purchase WHERE productid=1001 AND purchasedate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR GROUP BY m, y
```

it return 11 months data from last purchase date

```
2015 1 9177
2015 2 9914
2015 3 11672
2015 4 10521
2015 5 11873
2015 6 10449
2015 7 4057
2014 9 340
2014 10 9913
2014 11 8451
2014 12 7857
```

but it should return 12 months data.

```
    2015 1 9177
    2015 2 9914
    2015 3 11672
    2015 4 10521
    2015 5 11873
    2015 6 10449
    2015 7 4057
    2015 8 0
    2015 9 0
    2014 10 9913
    2014 11 8451
    2014 12 7857
```

What I am doing wrong. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT d.y, d.m, p.cnt 
FROM 
    (SELECT a.y, b.m 
    FROM (SELECT 2015 AS Y UNION ALL SELECT 2014 AS Y) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 11 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 12 AS m) b
    WHERE CONCAT(a.y, '-', b.m, '-01') BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 MONTH AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    ORDER BY 1, 2) d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT YEAR(purchasedate) AS Y ,MONTH(purchasedate) AS m, COUNT(*) cnt FROM purchase WHERE productid=1001 AND purchasedate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR GROUP BY m, Y) p ON d.m=p.m AND d.y=p.y
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2
```

You are not doing anything wrong, but MySQL cannot return rows for months that do not exist in your data-set. To solve this problem, you need to provide all months your self (table `d` in this query) and `LEFT JOIN` them with results from your data-set

Comment: suppose I have data from last 6 years, so my d table should have 6*12 = 72 entries like (id y m)
1 2009 1, 2 2009 2, 3 2009 3.... so on

Comment: @Alvi_1987, No, the table `d` contains two tables `a` & `b`. Now `a` lists all the years you want and `b` lists all possible 12 months. Currently `a` returns years 2015 and 2014 only, If you want to add more years then just add `UNION ALL SELECT 2013 AS y` and so on in `a`'s sub-query. The `CROSS JOIN` will handle multiplication for you