# Mysql get monthwise record between dates even if month doesnt exist

Tags: mysql

I need to get the result of last two months, im having trouble if month doesnt exist in the database, and im getting month by date of course.
help please!

```
SELECT customer_no
     , SUM(`balance_due`)
     , MONTH(`transaction_date`) 
  FROM customers 
 WHERE customer_no = 'DCD017'
   AND `transaction_date` BETWEEN ( DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') -interval 1 month) AND LAST_DAY(NOW() )  
 GROUP 
    BY MONTH(`transaction_date`)
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more clearly, also provide sample data and your expected output to give a better understanding

Comment: I have a table in mysql, and a column named 'transaction_date' which has the date stored, now I need result of previous two months which i get successfully by using 
`transaction_date` BETWEEN ( DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') -interval 1 month) AND LAST_DAY(NOW() )
the issue is, if there's no record of last month query returns empty and of course it has to, but I want it to return the name of the month in which there wasnt any record. am I making sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetch data grouped by month using mysql interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865088/fetch-data-grouped-by-month-using-mysql-interval)

Comment: No no the answer you shared is different, in this , it shows all 12 months if data doesnt exist, I dont need this.

Lets make it simple:
Can you tell me a query to get the records of last 3 months i.e sep, aug, and july. If we dont have any record in july, the query should return july and zero with it. Possible?

Comment: You can easily change the sub-query for table `d` to get only last 2 months instead of 12